# Python: Paste Excel cells with win32com to Powerpoint without losing cell formats

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba, powerpoint, win32com

I want to copy and paste an Excel cell range to Powerpoint with PasteSpecial while preserving Excel cell formats. I use **Office 2016**.

My Excel workbook looks like this:

[image: screenshot excel cells]

You can download the Excel file here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uicqSQEEMJIttxW6r1_E8higTk2HXbtC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103651073926513131793&rtpof=true&sd=true

**I would like to reproduce a manual copying of cells in Excel and "paste special" in Powerpoint with the second paste option (`Keep Source Formatting (K)`)**

[image]

The result of the manual operation is an editable table with the format of the Excel source:

[image]

I use the following code to create a powerpoint presentation and copy the table data to the first slide of the presentation:

```py
import win32com.client

# initialize Powerpoint and get slide object
ppt_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
ppt_presentation = ppt_app.Presentations.Add(True)
ppt_presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
ppt_slide = ppt_presentation.Slides(1)


# load Excel file and get worksheet object
excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(Filename="my_excel_file.xlsx", ReadOnly=1)
worksheet = workbook.Sheets(1)
worksheet.Range("A1:H8").Copy()  # select cells and copy to clipboard


# paste cells to Powerpoint slide
ppt_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType=0, Link=False)
```

As a result of the Python script, cells are copied to Powerpoint as editable data (this is what I want, not as an image), but cell formats are lost:

[image]

**The script apparently applies the first paste option (`Use Destination Theme (H)`). I wonder how I could specify the second paste option here, to keep cell formats.**

I tried different DataType options of the `PasteSpecial` method, but it did not work. Either no format was applied, or cells were pasted as an image object.

```
ppt_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType=0, Link=False)
```

A list of all available DataType options (`PpPasteDataType`) is listed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.pppastedatatype

The `PasteSpecial`method is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.pastespecial

Does anyone have an idea how to paste Excel cells without losing format? Thank you!!

Comment: If you do the copy & paste manually (without Python) do you get the result you want? If not, then you won't have any more success using Python ...

Comment: Have a go with `DataType=10`. That embeds an object.

Comment: @DS_London Thank you for the suggestion. However, when using `DataType=10`, the pasted object is not editable and appears to me as a pasted image.

Comment: @DS_London Yes, when I do it manually, I get the result I want. I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: When I use `10` in a Powerpoint macro, it pastes an OLE object, which I can click into (and acts as a mini Excel s/sheet).

Comment: @DS_London Interesting, does not work with my setup (Office 2016). Thank you for checking!

Answer (score 4):

I just found a workaround, avoiding the `PasteSpecial` method of the `Shapes` object. Instead, I use a macro execution method of the Powerpoint application object:

```py
ppt_app.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")
```

Here the complete working code:

```py
import win32com.client

# initialize Powerpoint and get slide object
ppt_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
ppt_presentation = ppt_app.Presentations.Add(True)
ppt_presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)


# load Excel file and get worksheet object
excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(Filename="my_excel_file.xlsx", ReadOnly=1)
worksheet = workbook.Sheets(1)

worksheet.Range("A1:H8").Copy()  # select cells and copy to clipboard


# paste cells to Powerpoint slide with macro command
ppt_app.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")
```

Comment: I cannot use this command when I specified that powerpoint app runs in the background